# How to handle cases where Selenium click action succeeds, but nothing happens

Tags: c#, selenium, coded-ui-tests

I am using Selenium to test the user interface of a website. 95% of the time, things work fine. I find my elements, execute my clicks, and check the results. Unfortunately, maybe 5% of the time, I'll find the element, verify that it is clickable, run the click event with no error... but nothing actually changes.

Here's an example bit of code:

```
WebDriverWait waitForTimeout = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));

IWebElement selectMaskButton = waitForTimeout.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("mask_expander")));
Thread.Sleep(250);  // A slight delay ensures that the button really is clickable
selectMaskButton.ClickAndWait(Driver);
```

I have that sleep statement in there because this is a case where, frequently, that click event goes awry. The quarter second wait works most of the time, but not always. For this case, I could probably surround it with custom code to pause, and then click again if the specified follow-up element doesn't work out, but that's clunky and involves a different target for everywhere that I click on things. And adding delays everywhere is less than optimal too because it leads to a bunch of fixed delays that just keep getting incremented as people run into issues.

I don't know that it's entirely a matter of going too fast because I've had the occasional case where I set a debug statement on a Click command, run the test in debug, and waited a few seconds before executing the Click, and still it doesn't work. As a tester, I don't have access to some of the inner code, so I don't know exactly what gets executed inside the click, and the developers I've spoken to are basically telling me that it works fine when they manually click on it, so they don't see the problem.

Is there a generic way to handle clicking on an element and ensuring that the action actually fires?

---

Additional code for helper function `ClickAndWait`:

```
public static void WaitUntilPageLoads(this IWebDriver driver)
{
    var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    wait.Until(d => ((RemoteWebDriver)d).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));
    Thread.Sleep(500);
}

public static void ClickAndWait(this IWebElement element, IWebDriver driver)
{
    element.Click();
    driver.WaitUntilPageLoads();
}
```

In this case, ClickAndWait actually isn't useful because the page is changing dynamically rather than all at once, so the page claims to be loaded right away. I had just forgotten to replace the call.

Comment: What is the code in ClickAndWait?  that is probably where we need to look for the problem.

Comment: Ah. I forgot that was a custom call. It's nothing useful for the question, but I'll post it.

Comment: You said "the page is changing dynamically". Is it possible that the page draws, fires off a background call to the API, your code clicks on the button, then the API call comes back and the **same** page redraws effectively ignoring your click? This behaviour is not uncommon in AJAX heavy pages.

Comment: I suppose that's possible. If so, how can I detect the behavior and account for it?

Comment: I think that you need to have a conversation with the developers to understand what's going on with this click.  They may be able to give you some clues.  On my pages, I found out that I could use some JavaScript to determine when all of the AJAX calls were done.  That made a huge difference.